# Set image to a custom listview to a specific position with in the listview

Tags: java, android

its me again "Newbee" im very new with this android developement,.My Concern is , I have a custom list view and i wanted to set a Specific image to a Specific position in the listview How can i do that?

this is my Main activity

```
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        database.getReference()
                .child("Users").child("Displayname")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                         //   System.out.println(snapshot.getKey());

                            Map<String, Object> map =(Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){

                                Cred = (String) entry.getValue();


                                int numberOfUsers = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                                UsersNumber.setText("Total Users : "+String.valueOf(numberOfUsers));
                                professions = new String[numberOfUsers];
                                Prof.add(Cred);
                                professions = new String[Prof.size()];
                                Prof.toArray(professions);
                                friend = snapshot.getKey();
                                names = new String[numberOfUsers];
                                Usersname.add(Cred+" "+friend);
                                names = new String[Usersname.size()];
                                Usersname.toArray(names);
                                names = new String[Usersname.size()];
                                Usersname.toArray(names);

                                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                                String User = bundle.getString("MyUser");
                                String UserDisplay = bundle.getString("UserDisplayName23");
                                FirebaseDatabase database1001 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                DatabaseReference myRef1001= database1001.getReference(User + "     " + UserDisplay).child("Status");
                              //  myRef1001.setValue(String.valueOf("Online"));



                                customListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view);
                                userInfos=new ArrayList<>();
                                customListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view);
                                userInfos=new ArrayList<>();
                               // Arrays.sort(names, Collections.reverseOrder());//  Arrays.sort(names, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
                                Arrays.sort(names, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
                                customListAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(userInfos,MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this);
                                customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
                                getDatas();

                                 customListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this,String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        UserData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }

.....

private void getDatas(){


        for(int count=0;count<names.length;count++){

            userInfos.add(new UserInfo(names[count],professions[count],photos[count]));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_option,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                newText=newText.toString();
                ArrayList<UserInfo> newUserInfos=new ArrayList<>();

                for(UserInfo userInfo:userInfos){
                    String name=userInfo.getName().toLowerCase();
                    String profession=userInfo.getProfession().toLowerCase();
                    if(name.contains(newText) || profession.contains(newText)){
                        newUserInfos.add(userInfo);
                    }
                }
                customListAdapter.filterResult(newUserInfos);
                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }





}
```

this is my usersinfo.java

```
public class UserInfo {
    private String name,profession;
    private int photo;

    public UserInfo(){}

    public UserInfo(String name, String profession,int photo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.photo = photo;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public int getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }


}
```

I know its incorrect but for the purpose for my app publish ontime i did this to get the Photos.
It's inside the ***Mainactivty by the way***. i wanted to set the user's images to be `R.drawable.waiting` after if the user's position is more than ***10*** `R.drawable.rank10`
it will work as of the moment ,but if the users increase to morethan 2000 it will crash. 
could any one please help me with this?.

```
  private List<String> friends = new ArrayList<>();
   // private String[] names ;
    private String[] names ;
    private String[] professions ;



   // private int[] photos={
  //  R.drawable.sample_5

    List<String> Usersname = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> Prof = new ArrayList<String>();




    private int[] photos = new int[]{

            R.drawable.rank1,
            R.drawable.rank2,
            R.drawable.rank3,
            R.drawable.rank4,
            R.drawable.rank5,
            R.drawable.rank6,
            R.drawable.rank7,
            R.drawable.rank8,
            R.drawable.rank9,
            R.drawable.rank10,

            R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting,
            R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting,
            R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting,
            R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting,
            R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, R.drawable.waiting, and so on..................................



    };
```

Comment: Remove all of the R.drawable.waiting from photos[] array. Only ten elements will do. After that change `userInfos.add(new UserInfo(names[count],professions[count],photos[count]));` to `if (count<10)   userInfos.add(new UserInfo(names[count],professions[count],photos[count])); else   userInfos.add(new UserInfo(names[count],professions[count], R.drawable.waiting);`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @ blackapps  ,ill try it now.